# Vue render component as modal in specific route if route metadata key is set to true

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm using vue-router and i'm trying to create a functionality as follows:

I want to be able to specify in the router routes if a component should be rendered in modal or not. And if it is rendered in Modal keep every component below ( under modal-mask ) as it was.
I've created a modal-wrapper component that have basic modal structure and `slot` inside its modal body so the component I want to render should go in the `slot`. But how to achieve that. Does `Vue-Router` have options for that functioanlity.

Router routes:

```js
{
  path: '/customers/:clientId',
  component: customerView
  meta: {
    auth: true,
  },
},
{
  path: '/customers/:clientId/addAddress',
  component: dataViewAdd
  meta: {
    openInModal: true,
    auth: true,
  },
},
```

Since if component should be rendered inside modal while overlaying the previous router-view, I guess ill need 2 router-views.

```html
<router-view class="normal-view"></router-view>
<router-view class="modal-view" name="modal-view"></router-view>
```

Comment: Does it matter where in the DOM the modal is, or can you just rely on fixed positioning? Is the `dataViewAdd` component used in any other place or route?

Comment: the modal does not matter it will be positioned with fixed. dataViewAdd will be used for many routes ill just pass params to it so the component will render different things relative to from where it was navigated

Comment: Could you clarify "keep every component below (under modal-mask) as it was"? Do you want to "preserve" the previous route component when you navigate to the modal route?

Comment: exactly preserve it so the user can see what is below under the mask, modal mask means the overlay background ( usually black transparent )

Comment: Ok so you want to keep the `customerView` component visible (underneath the modal) when `dataViewAdd` is visible.

Comment: exactly this is what i want, but if dataViewAdd route object has `openInModal: false`, it should be displayed without customerView ( just dataViewAdd )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the component displayed in each modal route was not used in a non-modal context, then you can just modify the modal route component's template (`dataViewAdd`) so that the modal component is the root of the template. But you mentioned that you would be reusing these components in different situations (so one route might use `dataViewAdd` inside a modal and another route might use `dataViewAdd` not inside a modal).

You *could* create wrapper modal versions of each component, but that'll become messy; it looks like you just want to be able to specify `openInModal: true` and have it work for any component.

You also mentioned that the position of the modal in the DOM doesn't matter (otherwise I'd recommend using something like [`portal-vue`](https://github.com/LinusBorg/portal-vue) to assist with this).

First you'll need to change your router configuration so that the modal route is a child of the component you want to keep visible underneath it. Make sure `customerView` has a `<router-view>` inside it.

Create a helper function which returns a modal-wrapped version of the component and use that as the route component. This doesn't use the `openInModal` meta property, but it works in a similar way.

The following code is untested.

```js
import Modal from './modal.vue';

function wrapInsideModal(childComponent) {
  return {
    functional: true,
    render(h) {
      return h(Modal, [h(childComponent)]);
    },
  };
}

// Routes
{
  path: '/customers/:clientId',
  component: customerView,
  meta: {
    auth: true,
  },
  children: [
    {
      path: 'addAddress',
      component: wrapInsideModal(dataViewAdd),
    },
  ],
},
```